# PHP (CodeIgniter) 301 redirect http to https

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, server

I'm trying to force https if the site has an SSL certificate. I can confirm the code does work, in that it DOES do the redirect but it ends up infinitely looping, though I'm not sure why. The redirect should only take place if the server port is not 443 and I'd assume after the first redirect, the user should then be using port 443.

Here's my code;

```
// If they're using a masking domain and they own an SSL certificate, force SSL

    $this->db->where('client_id', $client['client']);
    $result = $this->db->get('ssl_certs')->row_array();

    // only run this function if there is a date in this field

    if (!empty($result['ssl_completed_date']))
    {
        // if they're not using https, redirect them to https

        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)
        {
            $redirect = 'https://www.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/website';
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Location: ' . $redirect);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to be careful of:

1) I believe the value returned is a string, not a number. (Not checked - but something to verify). It won't make a difference anyway as you're not doing !== but the relaxed !=

2) The manual, under the "server_port" (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) states

> Note: Under the Apache 2, you must set UseCanonicalName = On, as well as UseCanonicalPhysicalPort = On in order to get the physical (real) port, otherwise, this value can be spoofed and it may or may not return the physical port value. It is not safe to rely on this value in security-dependent contexts.

3) You'd be better off using the 'HTTPS' of the $_SERVER array. Details on the same page.

4) If behind a load balancer, you'll also want to check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])) {
    $isSecure = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https');
} else {
    $isSecure = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robbie for your detailed explanation! I changed checking SERVER_PORT to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO and it worked.

Comment: Good stuff. Add both the two above, then your script works behind load balancer or direct (in case you re-use on another site). Glad it's working.